# Using Bash, is it possible to store an array in a dictionary

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

With bash, it is possible to store an array in a dictionary?  I have shown some sample code of fetching an array from the dictionary but it seems to lose the fact that it is an array.

I expect it is the `dict+=(["pos"]="${array[@]}")` command but am unsure of how to do this or if it is even possible.

```
# Normal array behaviour (just an example)
array=(1 2 3)
for a in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$a"
done
# Outputs:
# 1
# 2
# 3

# Array in a dictionary
declare -A dict
dict+=(["pos"]="${array[@]}")

# When I fetch the array, it is not an array anymore
posarray=("${dict[pos]}")
for a in "${posarray[@]}"
do
    echo "$a"
done
# Outputs:
# 1 2 3
# but I want
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Comment: You may want to consider `ksh` if you want this level of data-structure support in a shell; otherwise, it's time to consider using a proper general-purpose programming language. In `ksh`, `set -A foo; foo[k]=(1 2 3); echo ${foo[k][1]}` outputs `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, but there are workarounds.

---

#### Using `printf '%q '` + `eval`

You can flatten your array into a string:

```
printf -v array_str '%q ' "${array[@]}"
dict["pos"]=$array_str
```

...and then use `eval` to expand that array back:

```
# WARNING: Only safe if array was populated with eval-safe strings, as from printf %q
key=pos; dest=array
printf -v array_cmd "%q=( %s )" "$dest" "${dict[$key]}"
eval "$array_cmd"
```

Note that this is only safe if your associative array is populated through the code using `printf '%q '` to escape the values before they're added; content that avoids this process is potentially unsafe to `eval`.

---

#### Using base64 encoding

Slower but safer (if you can't prevent modification of your dictionary's contents by untrusted code), another approach is to store a base64-encoded NUL-delimited list:

```
dict["pos"]=$(printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | openssl enc base64)
```

...and read it out the same way:

```
array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
  array+=( "$item" )
done < <(openssl enc -d base64 <<<"${dict["pos"]}"
```

---

#### Using Multiple Variables + Indirect Expansion

This one's actually symmetric, though it requires bash 4.3 or newer. That said, it restricts your key names to those which are permissible as shell variable names.

```
key=pos
array=( "first value" "second value" )

printf -v var_name 'dict_%q' "$key"
declare -n var="$var_name"
var=( "${array[@]}" )
unset -n var
```

...whereafter `declare -p dict_pos` will emit `declare -a dict_pos=([0]="first value" [1]="second value")`. On the other end, for retrieval:

```
key=pos
printf -v var_name 'dict_%q' "$key"
declare -n var="$var_name"
array=( "${var[@]}" )
unset -n var
```

...whereafter `declare -p array` will emit `declare -a array=([0]="first value" [1]="second value")`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the dangers that go along with the first workaround. It will work for me as I am in control of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are associative arrays, so the question rephrased is: "Is it possible to store an array inside another array?"

No, it's not. Arrays cannot be nested.

> ```
> dict+=(["pos"]="${array[@]}")
> ```

For this to work you'd need an extra set of parentheses to capture the value as an array and not a string:

```
dict+=(["pos"]=("${array[@]}"))
```

But that's not legal syntax.